# Suppose two functions that are equal on two subsets are continuous on it.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I have this lemma in my book (which is in French), and I see no use for it, and even don't see the point of why it should be proved. So here it is:

> Suppose $E$ and $E'$ are two normed vector spaces. Let $A \subset E$ and
>   $f:A \rightarrow E'$. Suppose also $V$ an open subset such that$V \subset A$ and $g: V \rightarrow E'$ defined as $g(x)=f(x)$ is continuous for all $x$. Then $f$ is continuous on V.

To me it seems trivial that if a function $f$ is equal to another function $g$ that is continuous on a subset, then $f$ is continuous on that subset. What's the point of this lemma? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following? take $A=E=E'=\mathbb{R}$ and take $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\forall x\in A,\ f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $x\geq0$}\\0&\text{if $x<0$.}\end{cases}$$
Then consider the case $V=\mathbb{R}_+$ (which is *not* open in $\mathbb{R}$). Clearly, the function $g:V\to\mathbb{R}$ equal to the restriction of $f$ on $V$ is continuous, yet $f$ is not continuous on $V$ (since $f$ is not continuous at $0$ and $0\in V$). I think the purpose of the lemma is to emphasize the importance of the openness of the subsets considered when you want to study continuity locally. And your sentence:

> To me it seems trivial that if a function $f$ is equal to another function $g$ that is continuous on a subset, then $f$ is continuous on that subset.

now probably looks wrong (when that subset is not open!).

Comment: You definitely cleared it up for me! Thank you! Btw, I like your nick ;)

Comment: I thought $\mathbb R^+$ denoted the positive reals,which is an open set.  Also $f(x)=g(x)=1$ for $x>0,$ and if you change $V$ to $[0,\infty)$ we still have $g(0)=1.$....  The usual meaning of " $f$ is continuous on $V$" is that $f^{-1}U$ is open in the subspace $V$ whenever $U$ is open.... I think something got lost in translation from French to English,

Comment: @user254665: regarding $\mathbb{R}_+$, it depends on your convention. Here, of course, I mean $V=[0,+\infty)$; that's the convention used in France; it's actually written as $[0,+\infty\mathclose[$ there `:)`. I don't really understand your point about continuity of $f$ on a subspace, though.